# Transition Property for :hover only works once - How to make it work on every hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions, css-animations

Seriously struggling with CSS animations and transitions. Thanks to another user, I was able to fix one transition issue, but it gave me another. I'm working on my portfolio site, at http://jcdevelopmentsite.com/jcwebandgraphic/index.html. The 'Services' section has some Font Awesome icons that I'm applying these effects to. They work well, however, the transition off the hover state only works once per icon. How can I fix this to ensure a beautiful transition back to the initial state every time?

HTML

```
<section id='services-section'>
    <h2 class='highlight'>Services</h2>
    <div class='main-content'>
        <a href='#pricing-section'>
            <div class='services'>
                <i class='fa fa-laptop fa-4x'></i>
                <h5>Static & Fluid Layouts</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href='#pricing-section'>
            <div class='services'>
                <i class='fa fa-mobile fa-4x'></i>
                <h5>Responsive Layouts</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href='#pricing-section'>
            <div class='services'>
                <i class='fa fa-shopping-cart fa-4x'></i>
                <h5>E-Commerce Solutions</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href='#pricing-section'>
            <div class='services'>
                <i class='fa fa-pencil-square fa-4x'></i>
                <h5>Theme Customizations</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- Closes .main-content -->
</section>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes animate1 {
    from {}
    to { 
        background-color: #332D29;
        }
    }

.services {
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
    float: left;
    }

.services:hover {
    animation-name: animate1;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinity;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
```

Comment: They seem to be working for me. I am not sure what the issue is.